# How can i put total, average and grade of html form into mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have html form that generate total, average and grade automatic when inputs applied with the help of ajax. I am trying to put those data into database, but only input1, input2 and input3 are entered while total, average and grade do not enter. Please anyone can help me. Thank you in advance. Below is the code

```
<table class="input-table">
<tr>
    <th><?php echo htmlentities($row['SubjectName']); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo htmlentities($row['SubjectName']); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo htmlentities($row['SubjectName']); ?></th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Average</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
    <th>Remark</th>
</tr>
<tr class="input-table">
    <td>
        <input id="input1" class="input" type="number" value="0" name="input1[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="input2" class="input" type="number" value="0" name="input2[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="input3" class="input" type="number" value="0" name="input3[]">
    </td>
  
    <td class="total"></td>
    <td class="ave"></td>
    <td class="grade"></td>
    <td class="remark"></td>
</tr>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $inputTable = $('.input-table'),
    gradeColors = {
        'A': 'blue',
        'B': 'green',
        'C': 'yellow',
        'D': 'red',
        'E': ''
    };

function size(obj) {
    var size = 0,
        key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

function checkGrade(average) {

    var grade = '--';

    if (average >= 80) {
        grade = 'A';
    } else if (80 > average && average >= 60) {
        grade = 'B';
    } else if (60 > average && average >= 40) {
        grade = 'C';
    } else if (40 > average && average >= 20) {
        grade = 'D';
    } else if (20 > average && average >= 0) {
        grade = 'E';
    }
 
    return grade;
}


function evaluate() {

    var $this = $(this),
        $group = $this.parent().parent(),
        $inputs = $group.find('.input'),
        number = null,
        total = 0,
        average = 0,
        gradeMessage = '',
        // Values from the input fields for saving.
        values = {},
        text = '--';
 
    // Remove previous error.
    if ($group.next().hasClass('error')) {
        $group.next().remove();
    }
    
    $inputs.each(function (key, value) {
        number = $(value).val();
        number = parseInt(number, 10);

        // Store the value.
        if (isNaN(number)) {

            // Break the loop and show the error.
            $('<tr></tr>').addClass('error').text('Inputs must be numbers').insertAfter($group);
            return false;
        } else {
            values['input' + key] = parseInt(number, 10);
            total += values['input' + key];
        }
    });

    if (size(values) === 3) {

        // Calculate average.
        average = total / 3;
        grade = checkGrade(average);
        gradeMessage = $('<div></div>').text(grade);

        if (gradeColors[grade]) {
            gradeMessage.addClass(gradeColors[grade]);
        }

        // Update the grade.
        $group.find('.grade').empty().html(gradeMessage);
        $group.find('.total').text(total);
        $group.find('.ave').text(average);
    }
};

$inputTable.on('change', '.input', evaluate);
</script>
```

Comment: because , they are *td* tags and they do not get submitted to server

Answer (score 0):

Only form fields (`<input>`) get sent to the server when submitting a form. In order to send the total/average/grade fields to the server, you need to change them to `<input>`. Give them a `name`, the `readonly` attribute to make sure the user doesn't write into them:

```html
<td>
    <input class="ave" name="ave" readonly>
</td>
```

Also make sure your Javascript sets their `value` (a property that exists only for input elements) as opposed to their content (`innerHTML` or similar).

Be aware that there is no guarantee that the values that arrive at the server are actually the real values your script calculated; the user might have modified them anyway (`readonly` is only a recommendation for the browser, which you can't entirely enforce).

Alternatively, it might be safer and easier to calculate these three values again on the server side in PHP, if possible.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i am new in coding, i tried to change them to <input> but i got blank average, total, grade and remark. To set their value on JavaScript troubled me. Please help.

Comment: i add up the javascript above to see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I guess you are doing is having a form tag around your code and are doing a POST request on submit...?

If so, the only data that gets submitted is what is inside of inputs, so you should either change the `td`s of `class=` `total`,`ave`,`grade` and `remark` into inputs. The way I would do it is by adding an `<input type="hidden" ... >`, `<input ... disabled>` or `<input ... readonly>` inside the `td`s

So the html would like something like this:

```
<tr class="input-table">
    <td>
        <input id="input1" class="input" type="number" value="0" name="input1[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="input2" class="input" type="number" value="0" name="input2[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="input3" class="input" type="number" value="0" name="input3[]">
    </td>
  
    <td><input class="total" name="total[]" readonly /></td>
    <td><input class="ave" name="ave[]" readonly></td>
    <td><input class="grade" name="grade[]" readonly></td>
    <td><input class="remark" name="remark[]" readonly></td>
</tr>
```

And then change the javascript so you change the input values instead of adding text inside the `<td>`s, like so:

```
function evaluate() {
   [...]
   $group.find('.grade').val(grade);
   $group.find('.total').val(total);
   $group.find('.ave').val(average);
   [...]
}
```

Please note a couple of things:

1. I have not set the type of the inputs, so they will revert to text, which I do not know if that would be good or not for your use case
2. I am using `grade` instead of `gradeText` because adding the `<div></div>` would show that inside the input
3. You will probably want to style those elements
4. I couldn't find where you set the remarks, but I think you can follow this as an example to do whatever you want with those as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried to add <input type="hidden"> disabled and readonly inside the td's. The results i got is blank on total, average, grade and remark after type the inputs on the html form.

Comment: You are adding the values in the td, you must add that as a value in the inputs instead

Comment: Can you please give me an example on how to do it? I am new in coding. Thanks@Ant

Comment: Sorry for the delay, you can check the edited answer

Comment: Thanks @Ant, thank you very much, the solution you gave me worked very well, thanks again, be blessed.